# What does mean these chinese instruction on a 4-20mA water depth sensor?

Tags: translation

I have received a 4-20mA water depth sensor with no notice in english. I cannot even type it to get an automatic translation.

Could you help me please? Here are two photos:

[image]

[image]

Usually, such a sensor is simple to enforce, but 4 wires are expected and this one has only 2. Then I hope from the translation.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**Note: The two conveying tubes (behind) must also be completely wrapped (connected), not only wrap (connect) the two wires.**

It implies there are 4 connections to be made, though I don't know the difference between the two types (tube vs wire).

[image]

Fluid Level Sensor (or transimitter)

Range: 0 - 3 Meters

Output: 4-20 mA

[image]

The upper first three letters "Do not touch.."

The lower letters "Tear apart not..."

I guess it means "Do not touch the label. The warranty is waived if it is torn apart/destroyed/damaged".

The letters on the body of the device list the supplier's address and phone number. The rest words are illegible.

Comment: Thanks @r13, could you also translate the other inscriptions please?

Comment: For your first translation, with the help of concurrent products, I could understand they warn to connect the power supply ground to the analog input ground.